# How to get opening and closing brackets pair of string

Tags: javascript

I want to find opening and closing brackets pairs with indexes in string after split for example am providing string

```
var str="class User{      constructor(name=null){ if(name !=null){ this.name=name; }else{  
this.name=`Created by Test`; } } sayHello(){     
 console.log(`Welcome to Testing`); } 
showName(){ console.log(`This is ${this.name} this side`); 
if(true){  }else{  } } } function testing(){};    
 class Details { constructor(name=null){ if(name !=null){ this.name=name; }else{ 
 this.name=`Created by Tester`; } }
 sayName(){ console.log(`Welcome to Test2`); } }"; 

str=str.split(' ').filter(n => n).join(' ');  //replaces extra spaces with none
var strArr= str.split(" "); //by using this array of string find index pair,
```

I have to find array of opening closing pair of each classes like [{'class':'User','index_pair':[11,closing index of class brackets]},{'class':'Details','index_pair':[opening index of this class brackets,closing index of class brackets]}]

Thanks! Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you may be better off explaining the scenario that has lead to you to wanting to parse code with RegEx. It feels as though a better solution should exist.

Comment: I don't feel like regex is the best solution here. It should be fairly easy to do by just parsing the string and counting characters looking for brackets and keeping track of what's open and what isn't with a stack.

Comment: I do agree with @BlueWater86 too - this does appear to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @VLAZ,  I want to find it after split the string by space (as you see in last row with var strArr), because that index will be for later use so that's why want them as explained in my question .

Comment: @BlueWater86  I want as described with VLAZ